# Can you reference the contents of File A within File B in Linux?

Tags: linux, alias

I'd like to store my aliases in a Bitbucket repo, then locally maintain a segregated file for information specific to the environment in which I use them.

I'm hoping to build a .bash_alias file that can dynamically import the contents of another file, a bit like `require_once()` in PHP, or `@import` in CSS, so something like this:

**mySystem contents:**

```
myLocation='/path/to/stuff/specific/to/my/environment'
```

**.bash_alias contents:**

```
@import mySystem

backup () {
    cp <filename> "$myLocation"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have the right idea, you just need to adjust the syntax. Replace `@import mySystem` with `source mySystem`. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230079/can-you-reference-the-contents-of-file-a-within-file-b-in-linux/36230108#36230108) provided below is correct. I just thought it'd be nicer to point that you are almost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` can do this. You can "import" the contents of the other file using the `source` command.

Let's say you have some environment configuration in `my-env.sh`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"

alias ls="ls -l"
```

You can `source` this file from another script, including `.bash_aliases`, executing all commands in the same shell context:

```
#!/bin/bash <-- This line is not required in the referencing file
source my-env.sh
```

You could use `wget` or `git clone` the file into a known path, and `source` it. `bash` will execute the commands in `my-env.sh` within the same shell context.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example of what goes where?

Comment: Thanks! So using that, I'd put `#!/bin/bash source my-env.sh` *inside* the `.bash_alias` file?

Comment: You don't need the `#!` line in `.bash_alias`. Basically, `source` is the `@import` command you were looking for.